# Sql Query to get only non null values in a row in Sql Sever

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How to get columns with only non null values.

Say Output of **CTE1** is

```
ColA , ColB , ColC , ColD , ColE

1    , 2, NULL, NULL, NULL
```

So in I must write a **CTE2** that takes **CTE1** (ColA to Col E) (ONLY ONE ROW ALWAYS) as Input 
and returns only Non null Values i.e Only ColA and ColB

Remember that Number of Non null Values may vary and we have a list Non null values followed by NULL values. and i need to extract only Non Null Values

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

This involves `Unpivoting`,`Pivoting` and `Dynamic Query`.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max),@col_list varchar(500)='' 

;WITH cte1 AS 
(
SELECT * 
FROM   Yourtable )
,cte2 AS
( 
SELECT col_name, 
       val 
FROM   cte1 
CROSS apply (VALUES 
                   ('cola',cola) 
                  ,('colb',colb)
                  ,('colc',colc)
                  ,('cold',cold)
                  ,('cole',cole) ) cs (col_name,val)) 

SELECT @col_list += col_name+',' 
FROM   cte2 
WHERE  val IS NOT NULL

SET @col_list = LEFT(@col_list,Len(@col_list)-1)

SET @sql = '  ;with cte1 as 
             (select * from tst  ),
                    cte2 as  
             (select col_name,val from cte1    
             cross apply (values(''cola'',cola),(''colb'',colb), 
               (''colc'',colc),(''cold'',cold),(''cole'',cole)  ) cs
              (col_name,val))  
           select* from cte2  
          pivot (max(val) for col_name in ('+@col_list+')) p'

EXEC Sp_execute 
  @sql
```

- [**SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/773b97/7)